# Calling xmlhttprequest open() and send() from function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am running into a problem. I am trying to send a get request from a form using the form's onsubmit='function();' and ajax.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        window.alert("readystate change: " + xmlhttp.readyState + " , " + xmlhttp.status); 
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('adminPanel').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    function submit_password(){
        xmlhttp.open("GET","./src/admin_pass.php");
        xmlhttp.send();         
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit='submit_password();'>
        <input type='password' placeholder='PASSWORD'>
    </form>
    <div id='adminPanel'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
    echo "test text";
?>
```

What is happening is when I make the calls from within the function using form submit I get status=0 error. If I remove the function and let everything run at once it executes just fine. Why is this? I have been googling for a while now and can find no examples that do the same thing I'm trying to do. I'll probably end up using jQuery's ajax function in the end, but I really wanted to avoid including it just for this.

EDIT: OK so all I've been able to find out is that the XMLhttprequest status=0 means there was a http connection error. So maybe something wrong with my url? I don't think that's the case because the structure I have looks like this:

```
root
    src
        admin_pass.php
```

Do I actually need to put http:// localhost/src/admin_pass.php? I've used relative url in test work before and it was fine.

EDIT: Added full example

FIXED:

To be honest, I don't know why this fixed the problem. I figured from some of the responses that the issue might be in using a form. I decided it was unnecessary.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>     
    function submit_password(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            window.alert("readystate change: " + xmlhttp.readyState + " , " + xmlhttp.status); 
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('adminPanel').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","./src/admin_pass.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();         
    }
    function check_enter(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            submit_password();
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='password' type='password' placeholder='PASSWORD PLEASE' onkeyup='check_enter(event);'>

<div id='adminPanel'> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a small and complete example? (That is, it should contain all the code necessary for someone else to reproduce the problem, but be as short as possible.) Currently, it's not obvious from your code how `submit_password` is being invoked.

Comment: ./src/admin_pass.php is fine

Comment: I'm running XAMPP. I added full code to test.

Comment: Are you cancelling the form submit? The code you've provided here doesn't do that.

Comment: Maybe it is only a `localhost` vs. `127.0.0.1` conflict and cross-domain policy. See my edited answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare it globaly. 
Try the above code instead.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function submit_password(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     window.alert("readystate change: " + xmlhttp.readyState + " , " + xmlhttp.status); 
     if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('adminPanel').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","./src/admin_pass.php");
    xmlhttp.send();         
}
</script>
```

Comment: As you have done here, I would suspect you'd need a new instance of XMLHttpRequest's object for each time they do a submit at the very least.

Comment: I had this previously. It does the same thing for some reason. Any time I am calling from within a function it does this.

My initial idea was that the onreadystatechange value needed to be set globally, but that didn't fix it. Now I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

The status 0 comes when you have an error. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38djN/) out. Change the url of the request from `/` to `http://google.com` and you will get the status 0.

Are you sure you try to make a request on the same domain? (I see that you do in your example above, but to make sure you did not give here a different example than what you actually use).

The fiddle with status 0 is [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/38djN/2/)

One more thing that comes into my mind is if you use `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` you should try to be consistent because browsers are not. :) So start your server on `127.0.0.1` and to make sure, give it a test with an absolute URL containing `127.0.0.1`. Also the browser page should point to the same `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Damnit, why does this work in jsfiddle but not on my machine?! The only difference between that and mine is the url is as above './src/admin_pass.php'.

Comment: Is your html inside src folder? (it shouldn't be)

Comment: @Baddja Note also that the first `readystatechange` event always reports the `status` as 0, but later events should report an actual HTTP code (unless there's been an error).

Comment: Note that on jsfiddle to make it work I also appended `return false;`  in onsubmit, and made `submit_password` a global variable instead of a function declaration